# Reading MifareClassic Tags throws java.io.IOException: Transceive Failed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, nfc, mifare

Recently I am trying to read a MifareClassic 1K card. After reading about the fact, that only certain phones with NXP chips are able to read those tags, and getting one of those I am facing a new problem.
The card I am trying to read throws the error mentioned in the title but only when running without stepping through the code.
Here some details:
At first, I took the NFCSample from Xamarin and changed some things:

```
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if(_inWriteMode)
        {
            _inWriteMode = false;
            var tag = intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;

            if(tag == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            MifareClassic mifc = MifareClassic.Get(tag);
            DisplayMessage("NFC recognized");
            try
            {
                mifc.ConnectAsync().Wait();
                DisplayMessage("Connected to Mifare Tag");
                DisplayMessage("SectorCount:" + mifc.SectorCount);
                DisplayMessage("BlockCount in Sector 1:" + mifc.GetBlockCountInSector(1));
                byte[] blargh = new byte[6];
                MifareClassic.KeyDefault.CopyTo(blargh,0);
                if(Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => mifc.AuthenticateSectorWithKeyA(1, blargh)).Result)
                {
                    DisplayMessage("Auth A Complete");
                    blargh = new byte[6];
                    MifareClassic.KeyDefault.CopyTo(blargh, 0);
                    if(Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => mifc.AuthenticateSectorWithKeyB(1, blargh)).Result)
                    {
                        DisplayMessage("Auth B Complete");
                        DisplayMessage("Read All Blocks of Section 1 ...");
                        int firstBlock = mifc.SectorToBlock(1);
                        int lastBlock = firstBlock + 3;
                        List<byte[]> lstBlocks = new List<byte[]>();
                        for(int i = firstBlock; i < lastBlock; i++)
                        {
                            DisplayMessage("Read Block " + i);
                            byte[] block = mifc.ReadBlockAsync(i).Result; //fails without stepping through in Debug mode
                            lstBlocks.Add(block);
                        }
                        string BlockData = string.Empty;
                        foreach(var item in lstBlocks)
                        {
                            BlockData += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(item) + "\r\n";
                        }
                        DisplayMessage(BlockData);
                    }
                }
                DisplayMessage("Close Connection");
                mifc.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayMessage(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

So, if I step through the code ReadBlock/ReadBlockAsync works perfectly fine. Without breakpoints it will throw the exception mentioned above. Whats wrong here?

Edit:
The StackTraces of the Exceptions:
Outer Exception:

```
One or more errors occurred.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00014] in <filename unknown>:0  
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Byte[]].GetResultCore (Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x00034] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Byte[]].get_Result () [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0  
at NfcXample.MainActivity.OnNewIntent (Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x001d0] in c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\monodroid-samples-master\\NfcSample\\MainActivity.cs:94 "
```

Inner Exception:

```
Exception of type 'Java.IO.IOException' was thrown.
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0  
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:195
at Android.Nfc.Tech.MifareClassic.ReadBlock (Int32 p0) [0x00044] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-10/src/generated/Android.Nfc.Tech.MifareClassic.cs:360  
at Android.Nfc.Tech.MifareClassic+<ReadBlockAsync>c__AnonStorey2.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-10/src/generated/Android.Nfc.Tech.MifareClassic.cs:367  
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Byte[]].InnerInvoke () [0x00012] in <filename unknown>:0  
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in <filename unknown>:0  
--- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.io.IOException: Transceive failed
at android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:52)
at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:151)
at android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic.readBlock(MifareClassic.java:425)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Show us the stacktrace... Also note that it's pretty useless to authenticate with both key A and key B as only the last authenticate command will be effective. Typically you would try to authenticate with key B and only if that fails authenticate with key A (or even use only one of the two at all).

Comment: Okay, didn't know about the authentication thing. I've spent some time trying to get some data out of that card, and after both authentications and stepping through the code it worked. The failing line is the one reading the blocks. `byte[] block = mifc.ReadBlockAsync(i).Result;`

Comment: @MichaelRoland what you said about the authentication seems to be wrong as the connection breaks up everytime I try to authenticate with B only.

Comment: Is your card (actually: that sector) setup for authentication with key B? Note that you need to reconnect to the card after every authentication failure.

Comment: All I can say is, that I need both keys for full access. All Sectors have the same access modifier : FF078069. 69 is the GPB.The C1C2C3 of Block 0-2 is configured to 000, the last Block(Sector Trailer) is configured to 001. As I'm new to NFC and MifareClassic, I cannot decrypt what that exactly means.

Comment: Well, that configuration means that there is no key B. Hence, whenever you try to authenticate using key B, you actually break communication. Don't authenticate with key B and your communication should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT'S TOO FAST!
The device is reading the card to damn fast. After inserting a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` it finally worked! The for-loop now looks like this:

```
for(int i = firstBlock; i < lastBlock; i++)
{
    if(mifc.IsConnected)
    {
        DisplayMessage("Read Block " + i);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        byte[] block = mifc.ReadBlockAsync(i).Result;
        lstBlocks.Add(block);
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayMessage("Card Disconnected");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Every time you use `.Result` on a `Task`, god kills a kitten.

Comment: well... when I was posting this, I didn't know how to use async/await correctly. Now I do. The reason for that? Most of the time I have to work with .NET4 where async/await do not exist. Doesn't change the fact, that this is now the final Code getting shipped.